# Magento 2 - How do i edit qty in partial invoice?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, invoice

I want to edit qty in the partial invoice on my live website but won't be able to edit that for pending payment status, it's working fine for pending payment status. Attaching a screenshot for your reference.

[image]

But the same thing is working on my staging for the same payment status attaching a screenshot for your reference
[image]

So my question is, is there any setting to enable qty edit on the partial invoice for pending payment status? Pls, help!